# how to extract data from a large xml file from a url

Tags: xml

I have a large XML files containing huge data...and I want to access that XML and store some of the selective data into DB. If I open that xml in browser it takes huge time. Is there any tool which can download the XML locally so that I can analyze the nodes.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you using (Win, Linux, MacOS)? Do you want to save the file locally in your computer and read it afterwords or locally, on your server?

**Edit:** have you tried [Mindfusion's XMLViewer](http://www.mindfusion.eu/product1.html) ?

Comment: @punctweb..am using windows 64 bit OS

Comment: Yes i want to save it locally in system